# Is it possible to dockerize Azure cloud app?

Tags: azure, docker, cloud

We developed cloud app in Azure - it uses Azure Sql, Blob storage, Azure Queues, WebJobs, WebApp service and WebApp web.

Now we got requirement to provide Docker image for the app.

I don't know much about Docker and wonder what does it even mean for the app.
I just assume that it should be possible to run the app locally, without using the cloud services mentioned above. Is there any Docker image with private Azure infrastructure? Or does it mean we should rewrite the app to not use cloud services at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot dockerize azure components.

Instead, you can use Docker images by Microsoft to run Azure infrastructure locally. To be exact, they are images of compatible product like SQL Server against Azure SQL Database.

https://hub.docker.com/u/microsoft/

The tutorial by Docker would be helpful for you.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/aspnet-mssql-compose/

Because there are not images for Queues and WebJobs, you may have to rewrite some of your code.

Comment: Ok, I can understand I can use local SQL Server instead of SQL Azure, perhaps MSMQ or RabbitMq instead of Azure queue and find some locally installed alternatives that provides the functionality of other Azure components. But I don't understand how the app in docker can e.g. scale out? Azure SQL is in ElasticPool, Blob Storage, queues - I don't have to care if there is space enough, they are just services for me. I'm not getting what is the benefit of Docker against cloud application? Maybe it is improvement to IaaS but comparing to PaaS or SaaS, it is a step back, isn't it?

Comment: @eXavier The docker just make you use your infrastructure hardware more Efficient. And the docker images are smaller and easy to redeploy. Take a look at the Kubernetes, it may help you with the scale out of service.

Comment: Docker doesn't improve application performance or scalability. It improves development productivity or portability. You don't have to dockerize your application when you use PaaS because docker or other container technologies are already used. This blog post would help you. https://dzone.com/articles/top-10-benefits-of-using-docker